# Nest {% block %} in {% for %} Django template inheritance

Tags: python, django, django-templates, feed, template-inheritance

I am developing a dictionary application using Django. One of the main themes of the app is displaying feeds of definitions.

Specifically, I have:

1. an "index" feed where new definitions are listed,
2. a "headword" feed where definitions of a particular headword are listed,
3. and a "tag" feed where definitions tagged with a particular tag are listed.

**index.html**:

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>Definitions</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for definition in definitions %}
            // definition HTML
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

**headword.html**:

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>{{ headword }}</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for definition in headword.definitions_headword.all %}
            // definition HTML
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

**tag.html**:

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>{{ tag }}</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for definition in tag.definitions_tag.all %}
            // definition HTML
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Clearly, I need a base **feed.html** template that these three files can share. For the `h1` tag no problem. However, I am having problems with the for loop iterable variables.

I tried nesting a `{% block iterable %}{% endblock %}` in the for loop of **feed.html** as in `{% for definition in {% block iterable %}{% endblock %} %}` and then plugging definitions, headword.definitions_headword.all, and tag.definitions_tag.all in `{% block iterable %}`, but Django does not seem to support that.

I could probably pass to all three templates a "definitions" context variable and use that as the iterable in all three for loops, but is there a way to do it without touching Python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation was a bit fuzzy to me at the end there, but going just based off your first sentence of "Clearly, I need a base feed.html template that these three files can share."

I think {% include %} may be what you are looking for.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include

1. Create your base template of "feed.html" which includes generic variables.  Generic variables below are "header_name" and "definitions".

```html
<h1>{{ header_name }}</h1>
<ul>
    {% for definition in definitions %}
        // definition HTML
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

2. In your parent templates (index, headword, tag), use the "include" tag.  Pass in your parent template variables into the child template.  Examples below:

**headword.html**

```html
{% block body %}
    {% include 'pathname/feed.html' with header_name=headword definitions=headword.definitions_headword.all %}
{% endblock %}
```

**tag.html**

```html
{% block body %}
    {% include 'pathname/feed.html' with header_name=tag definitions=tag.definitions_tag.all %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you, man. That's probably what I was looking for. However, now I have a double navbar. Is the fact that feed.html extends base.html (which is where the navbar is) a problem? How can I avoid code duplication if that's the case?

Comment: Correct on the extends.  When you include a child template, that child template does not need to inherit/extend the base.  You can think of "include" almost as a reverse "extends".

Comment: Thank you, but how do I avoid duplicating my base.html code then? Right now my feed.html extends base.html and then, as you pointed out, index, headword, and tag.html include feed.html. This results in a double navbar. How would I change this so that I do not have to duplicate code?